# How to user variable form webdriver sampler in HTTP Header Manager

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am able to  extract auth_key from session storage .

I want load an API with auth_key in HTTP Header Manager

How can this be done.

```
var foo = WDS.browser.executeScript("return window.sessionStorage.getItem('ngStorage-jwtToken');")       
var obj = JSON.parse(foo);
vars.put("auth",obj.oauth_token)
WDS.log.info(vars.get('auth'))
```

And I want to use auth as global variable to access on all threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Replace this line:

   ```
   vars.put("auth",obj.oauth_token)
   ```

   with this one:

   ```
   WDS.vars.put("auth",obj.oauth_token)
   ```
2. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) as a child of the request which header you need to amend and configure it like:

   [image: JMeter HTTP Header Manager]

See [General Concepts](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/#General-concepts) section of the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/#Web-Driver-Sampler) user manual entry to learn what pre-defined variables are available for the scripting.

Comment: The variable - no, but JMeter Property - yes. In the WebDriver Sampler add the next line `WDS.props.put("auth",obj.oauth_token)` and in another thread group refer it using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like `${__P(auth,)}`. More information: [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups)

Answer (score 0):

Sdd [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) in scope with name `auth_key` and value `${auth}`.

`${auth}` will be updated with the value from webdriver sampler.